# How do I download beta apk for testing?

Tags: android, google-play

I'm trying to beta test an sdk that I uploaded to the developer console 2 days ago.

I have an apk currently published on production and a newer apk published in beta.

I followed all the steps (created google+ group, added testers, etc) but when I get to the `https://play.google.com/apps/testing/*****` page, it send me to the production app to download with an older version number.

So basically, I cannot download the beta apk from the play store, it makes me download the production version.

Has anyone ever had a similar experience? I'm trying to test out in-app purchases, but this is really putting a damper on my progress... any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: How recently did you set up the beta and add users? In my experience it can take around 24 hours to actually set it up.

Comment: The beta was published `May 27, 2015, 2:37:59 PM`. I just set up the test users today.

Comment: It might take a day or so before users can actually find it then

Comment: Publishing beta versions to Google Play is SLOW. Be patient. It should show up. You can always upload a new apk to beta with incremented versionCode. It might not help, but at least you'll feel like your doing something.

Comment: Could be so, seems strange to me that google doesn't document that type of information

Comment: @LeoLandau I have nothing to lose, I'll try that for now thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same question I did, the answer was simply to *wait*.